# How can I dynamically load configuration parameters in Magento?

Tags: magento, dynamic, configuration, system, external

I have a custom module in Magento with some system configuration fields, the classic database parameters for connection (host, user, pass, db name).
I successfully connect to external database ([link](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/create-external-database-connection/)) but I have to use static parameters like:

```
<phplist_database>
    <connection>
        <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[root]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[phplist]]></dbname>
        <model>mysql4</model>
        <type>pdo_mysql</type>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
```

How can I load that database parameter connection from my system\config parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $app = Mage::app('default');
    $config  = Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig("default_setup");
    $dbinfo = array('host' => $config->host,
                'user' => $config->username,
                'pass' => $config->password,
                'dbname' => $config->dbname
    );

    $hostname = $dbinfo['host'];
    $user     = $dbinfo['user'];
    $password = $dbinfo['pass'];
    $bank     = $dbinfo['dbname'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the database connection on the fly via resource.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$resource->createConnection('phplist_database', 'pdo_mysql', array(
    'host'     => Mage::helper('config')->getHost(),
    'username' => Mage::helper('config')->getUsername(),
    'password' => Mage::helper('config')->getPassword(),
    'dbname'   => Mage::helper('config')->getDbName(),
    'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    'type'     => 'pdo_mysql',
    'model'    => 'mysql4',
    'active'   => '1',
    'charset'  => 'utf8'
));
```